# make it after 3 o'clock

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, complements

I heard someone say "make it (the meeting) after 3 o'clock." To me, it sounded pretty idiomatic, but I was unsure as to the grammar of it.

"After three o'clock" is a prepositional phrase, then how does it come in the position of object complement? Is it grammatical to say it?

Comment: This is a little out of my depth, but it seems to me that prepositional phrases like “after 3 o’clock” act like adjectives (as in, “the meeting was after 3 o’clock”), and as such work fine as object complements with ***make***, which can take adjectival object complements (as in, “Make the coffee hot” or “Traffic makes me mad”).  This seems to be discussed [here](/q/27449/26083), [here](/q/53098/26083), and [here](/q/132201/26083).  Why do you question it?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think of "**Make it after 3 o'clock**" (short for "*of the clock*") as being verbal shorthand that I mentally expand into: "**Make** [*schedule*] **it** [*the meeting*] [*for some time*] **after** *1500 hours*."

I don't know if that helps at all. Cheers

Comment: Thank you. Maybe it's the shorthand of this; make it (meeting, schedule, etc) [some time] after 4'o clock. And it is idiomatic, right?

Comment: It is idiomatic/shorthand, yes.  For as many little rules as we have to try to keep straight, English _sure_ makes it a lot more complicated with an endless circus of idioms :)   It's a fun kind of mess, I suppose – Cheers

Comment: I was going to try to type a quick example, but now you've gotten me thinking about just _how many_ different phrases and ways people use "make"... wow.